# Import Accounts and Contacts Zip File via the Dynamics CRM SDK

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to automate the Dynamics CRM Import Wizard that currently lets you zip up Accounts and Contacts files together and import them into CRM all at once as per the screen shot below.

[image]

We have quite a few zip files to import so thought it might be wise to automate this using the Dynamics CRM SDK. Looking in the SDK I can find an example of importing entity files 1 by 1 such as [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547396.aspx) but no examples of importing them together in a zip file? Is this possible and if so are there any examples of this? For instance the SDK code below looks at an "Import Accounts.csv" file only but I really need something to handle an "Import Accounts and Contacts.zip".

```
// Create Import File.
ImportFile importFile = new ImportFile()
{
    Content = BulkImportHelper.ReadCsvFile("Import Accounts.csv"), // Read contents from disk.
    Name = "Account record import",
    IsFirstRowHeader = true,
    ImportMapId = new EntityReference(ImportMap.EntityLogicalName, importMapId),
    UseSystemMap = false,
    Source = "Import Accounts.csv",
    SourceEntityName = "Account_1",
    TargetEntityName = Account.EntityLogicalName,
    ImportId = new EntityReference(Import.EntityLogicalName, importId),
    EnableDuplicateDetection = false,
    FieldDelimiterCode =
        new OptionSetValue((int)ImportFileFieldDelimiterCode.Comma),
    DataDelimiterCode =
        new OptionSetValue((int)ImportFileDataDelimiterCode.DoubleQuote),
    ProcessCode =
        new OptionSetValue((int)ImportFileProcessCode.Process)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.importfileitem.filetypecode.aspx), the only options available for programmatic importing are xml and csv.  Have your code open each zip and submit each file individually.

**Update based on your comment:**
Disregard the enum.  I was hunting around the SDK for import related stuff and thought that enum was relevant.  Digging a little deeper, the metadatabrowser shows me that the importfile entity's filtetypecode optionset only has the following options: CSV, XML Spreadsheet 2003, Attachment, and XLSX.  So I'm guessing that the handling of zip files is baked into the dialog as opposed to the platform.  In other words, I think you're right, programmatic importing of zips is not looking good.

Comment: Hey are you sure this is correct? I noticed that the namespace this enum belongs to, namely Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector is no where to be found in the [Import Wizard API samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547418.aspx). It was just that the Import Wizard UI nicely handles all the relationships between the Contacts and Accounts automatically on import. I was hoping that the Import Wizard API would handle that too but it is not looking very likely.